# can't generate html file extent Report selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I worked with ExtentReports with selenium in visual studio C #, I ran the case tests, but the report file .html doesn't generate in the report folder that I created in solution explorer. I don't know where is the problem, I changed the path of the report file to check, and it still doesn't generate.
Here is my code:

```
 using NUnit.Framework;
 using RelevantCodes.ExtentReports;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExtentReportsDemo
{
[TestFixture]
public class BasicReport
{
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartReport()
    {
        string pth = 
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        Console.WriteLine("actual" + actualPath);

        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath; // project path 
                                                    of your solution
        //Console.WriteLine("project" + projectPath);
        string reportPath = projectPath + "Reports\\testreport.html";
        Console.WriteLine("report" + reportPath);

        // true if you want to append data to the report.  Replace existing 
        report with new report.  False to create new report each time
        extent = new ExtentReports(reportPath, false);
        extent.AddSystemInfo("Host Name", "MININT-F36S5EH")
            .AddSystemInfo("Environment", "QA")
            .AddSystemInfo("User Name", "testUser");

        extent.LoadConfig(projectPath + "extent-config.xml");

    }

    [Test]
    public void DemoReportPass()
    {
        test = extent.StartTest("DemoReportPass");
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
        test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, "Assert Pass as consition is true");

    }

    [Test]
    public void DemoReportFail()
    {
        test = extent.StartTest("DemoReportPass");
        Assert.IsTrue(false);
        test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, "Assert Pass as condition is false");

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void GetResult()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stackTrace = "<pre>" + 
  TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "</pre>";
        var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;

        if (status == NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, stackTrace + errorMessage);
        }
        extent.EndTest(test);

    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void EndReport()
    {
        extent.Flush();
        extent.Close();
    }

    }

}
```

and extent-config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <extentreports>
<configuration>
<!-- report theme -->
<!-- standard, dark -->
<theme>standard</theme>

<!-- document encoding -->
<!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

<!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
<!-- defaults to https -->
<protocol>https</protocol>

<!-- title of the document -->
<documentTitle>ExtentReports 2.0</documentTitle>

<!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
<reportName>Automation Report</reportName>

<!-- report headline - displayed at top-nav, after reportHeadline -->
<reportHeadline></reportHeadline>

<!-- global date format override -->
<!-- defaults to yyyy-MM-dd -->
<dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd</dateFormat>

<!-- global time format override -->
<!-- defaults to HH:mm:ss -->
<timeFormat>HH:mm:ss</timeFormat>

<!-- custom javascript -->
<scripts>
  <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

     });
    ]]>
   </scripts>

   <!-- custom styles -->
   <styles>
    <![CDATA[

  ]]>
</styles>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try first by Static location, like in any drive C:\ OR D:\ And check its generates for it,

If not, check with Debugger by updating Report termination call.

Also, Make sure your `EndReport()` method is calling in which report termination is calling there,

If so, Try to call `extent.EndTest(test);` in `EndReport()` method so you can check whether its calling or not.

If report is not calling for termination, it will not generate.

Comment: yes, I tried to put the static path and it doesn't work, and I even thought about debugging to check where the problem is located, but  I can't debugged because it's a class library so there is no point of execution.

Comment: If static path also not generating Report, I think  it might cause false property. ExtentReports(reportPath, false);

Comment: Also, I would like to suggest you, To use Extent Report 3

Comment: if I go to version 3, the code must change, ExtentReports doesn't take a parameter, extent.LoadConfig is not recognized..

Comment: As I said when I go to version 3, I have to change the code, do you have the program adapted to version 3. I tried so much and it doesn't work, and the project on which I work is the PerfSDK, a project in the Microsft Dynamics ax folder.

Comment: You can refer this Doc, And implement this example. 
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/net/#examples

Comment: I tried the example, and the file is not generated, I changed the path and I put it manually, and it doesn' work !

Comment: if because I import C# perf test from recording, means that I recorded  scenarios using task recorder on dynamics 365, and I imported them, later .cs files was generated. and I use selenium to execute this scenarios.